# why puppeteer gives me back a mobile screenshot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm creating a script to capture screenshots of web pages with puppeteer, I don't understand why on this site https://www.105.net/ I save the screenshot in a mobile version. do you have any suggestions?

with headless: false, I only save screenshots in the desktop version, while with headless: true, I save the screenshot in the mobile version.
I would always like to save in desktop version

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


//Larghezza e altezza del dispositivo - Desktop/Tablet/Mobile
const device_width = 1920;
const device_height = 1080;

//Patch di Chrome
var systemPath = '';
  if (process.platform == 'darwin'){
    console.log('Apro Chrome per MacOS');
    var systemPath = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome';

  }else if(process.platform == 'win64'){
    console.log('Apro Chrome per Windows 64bit');
    var systemPath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
}else {
    console.log('Apro Chrome per Windows 32bit');
    var systemPath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';
}

//Configuro le classi/id dei bottoni del network
const AME = 'button.amecp_button-accetto.iubenda-cs-close-btn';
var BtnCookie = [
  AME
];

//Render della pagina web
const waitTillHTMLRendered = async (page, timeout = 30000) => {
  const checkDurationMsecs = 1000;
  const maxChecks = timeout / checkDurationMsecs;
  let lastHTMLSize = 0;
  let checkCounts = 1;
  let countStableSizeIterations = 0;
  const minStableSizeIterations = 3;

  while(checkCounts++ <= maxChecks){
    let html = await page.content();
    let currentHTMLSize = html.length; 

    let bodyHTMLSize = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML.length);

    console.log('last: ', lastHTMLSize, ' <> curr: ', currentHTMLSize, " body html size: ", bodyHTMLSize);

    if(lastHTMLSize != 0 && currentHTMLSize == lastHTMLSize) 
      countStableSizeIterations++;
    else 
      countStableSizeIterations = 0; //reset the counter

    if(countStableSizeIterations >= minStableSizeIterations) {
      console.log("Pagina renderizzata completamente...");
      break;
    }

    lastHTMLSize = currentHTMLSize;
    await page.waitFor(checkDurationMsecs);
  }  
};

(async function () {

//Leggo il file delle URL
var fs = require('fs');
var urlArray = fs.readFileSync('url-list.js').toString().split("\n");

//Fai un ciclo per tutte le URL
for(var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++){
      
//Controllo se nel file list url sono prensenti spazi vuoti
//if (urlArray[i] != ''){
if (urlArray[i].indexOf("http") != '-1'){    

//Lancio Puppeteer
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
headless: true,
executablePath: systemPath,
args: ['--disable-gpu','--disable-extensions'],
defaultViewport: null});


//Apro il boswser, elimino la cache e setto le dimensioni della pagina
const page = await browser.newPage();
const currentAgent = await page.evaluate('navigator.userAgent');
console.log(currentAgent);
//await page.setUserAgent(currentAgent);
await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
await page.setViewport({width: device_width, height: device_height});
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');

   
//Dimmi su quale URL stai lavorando
console.log(' ');
console.log('Apro URL > '+urlArray[i]);
console.log(' ');
await page.goto(urlArray[i],{waitUntil:'networkidle2'}); 
//+'?bypassprivacy'
await page.waitFor(20000);
 
//Trova la classe/id del bottone in pagina
var contaNumeroValoriBtnCookie = BtnCookie.length;
for(var n = 0; n <= BtnCookie.length; n++){
    
    if (await page.$(BtnCookie[n]) !== null ) {
    await page.click(BtnCookie[n]);
    
    console.log('Bypass Cookie... OK!');
    break;
    }else if (n == contaNumeroValoriBtnCookie) {
     
        console.log('Cookie non trovato!');
    }else {
    
        //console.log('Cerco il cookie...');
    }

} //FINE - Trova la classe/id del bottone in pagina

await waitTillHTMLRendered(page);
await page.waitFor(20000);

//Configuro il CSS per i siti:
const urlCeck = new URL(urlArray[i]);

if (urlCeck.hostname == 'www.grazia.it'){
//console.log(urlCeck.hostname); // Logs: 'wwww.nomesito.it'
/* Spengo tutti gli article per evitare lo scroll infinito */
await page.addStyleTag({content: '#container-articles article.article-shadow {display:none;} #container-articles article:first-of-type {display:block !important;}'})
}

if (urlCeck.hostname == 'blog.giallozafferano.it'){
/* Disattivo il popup sui BlogAltervista se esistono! */
await page.addStyleTag({content: '#av-chatbot-banner, .av-push-notifications {display:none !important;}'})
}

if (urlCeck.hostname == 'www.smartworld.it'){
/* Spengo tutti gli article per evitare lo scroll infinito */
await page.addStyleTag({content: '#content article {display:none;} #content article:first-of-type {display:block !important;}'})
}

if (urlCeck.hostname == 'www.pianetadonna.it' || urlCeck.hostname == 'www.pianetamamma.it'){
/* Spengo tutti gli article per evitare lo scroll infinito */
await page.addStyleTag({content: '.foglia-speciale-scroll {display:none !important;}'})
}
  

//Scrolla tutta la pagina per caricare i contenuti
await autoScroll(page);

async function autoScroll(page){
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var totalHeight = 0;
          var distance = 100;
         
          var timer = setInterval(() => {
              var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
              window.scrollBy(0, distance);
              totalHeight += distance;

              if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                  clearInterval(timer);
                  resolve();
              }
          }, 300);
      });
  });
}

// Tortna in cima alla pagina
await page.evaluate(_ => {window.scrollTo(0, 0);});

await page.waitFor(20000);

//Pulisco l'URL prima di salvare il file
var str = urlArray[i];
str = str.replace(/[^\w]+/ig,'-');
var convertiUrl = str;

//Salvo lo screenshot
await page.screenshot({path: './screenshot/'+convertiUrl+i+'.jpg', fullPage: true}); //
console.log('Screenshot salvato con successo! :)');

//Fine
await page.close();
browser.close();

}  //end if (urlArray[i].indexOf("http") != '-1'){  

}//fine ciclo

})(); //end script
```

setUserAgent doesn't change based on your operating system?
I don't understand why if I insert the setUserAgent the page rendering function crashes

Comment: Maybe it identifies puppeteer as mobile device errorneously? Check your browsers headers vs puppeteers.

Comment: ok how should I do the rate? sorry but I'm not very experienced, I'm learning a little bit at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line

```
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
```

to send a header indicating you're using a desktop based browser.

Also don't forget to `await` the `page.setViewport` statement and It should work.

Here's a sample snippet to get you started:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const PAGE_URL = 'https://www.105.net/'; 

(async function () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
        args: ['--disable-gpu','--disable-extensions']});        

    const device_width = 1920;
    const device_height = 1080;

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
    await page.setViewport({width: device_width, height: device_height})
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');

    await page.goto(PAGE_URL, {
        timeout: 60000
    })

    await page.screenshot({
        path: './screenshot.jpg'
    })

    await page.close()
    await browser.close()

})()
```

Comment: thanks bro!I added your line and the script fails me.

Comment: is there a version for macos and windows?

Comment: const currentAgent = await page.evaluate('navigator.userAgent');

console.log(currentAgent);

await page.setUserAgent(currentAgent);

I'm trying in this way but I always save the screenshot in the mobile version ...

Comment: do try the snippet example I've added

Comment: thank you very much! see a console.log of my setUserAgent gives me this 'Mozilla / 5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome / 83.0.4103.97 Safari / 537.36'
setUserAgent does not change for the operating system in use?

Comment: Well, it should (for the page).  you must make sure to put the line `console.log(await page.evaluate('navigator.userAgent'))`  **After** the line `await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 …`.

Comment: thank you very much! now it seems worked!
last thing this userAgent: Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 61.0.3163.100 Safari / 537.36
will this userAgent also work on different operating systems running the macOs-like script?

Comment: Yes, It does. It's executed in the chrome instance - not natively.

Comment: I'm testing it and sometimes I get this error:

(node: 9064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: evaluation failed: TypeError: unable to read the 'innerHTML' property of null.
Before inserting userAgent it didn't give me this error.

Comment: Has got nothing to do with the solution I've provided (also with the original question). You can try reading the docs and experiment, and if the error persists, you should open a new question. Thanks